# Where to put the ca-certificate.crt file when using TLS for encrypted connection to MySQL on Digital Ocean managed db server

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate

I am trying to build a little demo app in Java 20 using JDBC 4.2+ by configuring a [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object via the `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` class. Developing on macOS Ventura, with IntelliJ 2023.1.

I created a MySQL instance on the [Digital Ocean managed database](https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases) service.

The Digital Ocean configuration page indicates that [SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) ([TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), actually, I presume) is required in connections to the database server. That same config page offers a download for a `ca-certificate.crt` file. I did download that file.

What do I do with this downloaded `ca-certificate.crt` file?

The [*How to Connect to MySQL Database Clusters*](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/mysql/how-to/connect/) page at Digital Ocean tells me to download the file, but does not say what to do with it.

The [*Configuring MySQL to Use Encrypted Connections*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-encrypted-connections.html) page on the MySQL site says a bunch of things, but does not say what to do with this file.

---

```java
private DataSource fetchDataSource ( )
{
    MysqlDataSource ds = null;
    try
    {
        ds = new MysqlDataSource();

        // Server
        ds.setURL( "jdbc:mysql://db-mysql-nyc1-whatever.db.ondigitalocean.com:25000/defaultdb" );
        ds.setRequireSSL( true );

        // User
        ds.setUser( "doadmin" );
        ds.setPassword( "tiger" );

        return ds;  // Happy path.
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException( "Failed to establish a JDBC DataSource. Msg # 3dfbbc6a-41d4-455d-9b6c-addf433522e5." );
}
```

Comment: That does not quite make sense, the crt is usually configured into the server with the site, so do you have a server on that domain?, or is it a personal certificate to send from a client program (very unlikely). A crt must be created (TLS nowadays) with the domain level it is sent from embedded in it, the crt key pair is then placed into that domain and registered into its configuration file.

Comment: Actually, anyone would be a piece lost to know it, it is usually a .pem    Here's the best I could find at a glance after sifting MySQL docs.       https://dev.to/developertharun/easiest-way-to-setup-mysqlmariadb-with-tlsssl-in-10-minutes-v105-any-os-ubuntu-focal-developer-tharun-4okc